# Looking to understand bounds in probability question

Tags: probability

I am wondering how the author came up with the solution for the triangular area below? (Ignore the B, it refers to a different part of the problem). But i am just confused on how this represents $y_{1} \le y_{2}$ can anyone help to clarify this?  ( Book is, Introduction to Mathematical Statistics, Wackerly)

Thanks

[image]

[image]

I am also really confused about how the bounds of integration are obtained (when trying to find a proper k) it gives [image]

but how is this done?  we are we evaluating $y_{1}$ from $0$ to $y_{2}$? when I try to draw the lines and such and make sense of the bounds, I can't seem to understand it. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you please consider converting at least the text part of the image to plain text? That makes the question more search friendly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture is unfortunate in that the axes are not labelled $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$.

I suggest you redraw the diagram for yourself, relabeling the $x$-axis as the $y_{1}$-axis and the $y$-axis as the $y_{2}$-axis.

Now the region indicated is all of the points $(y_{1},y_{2})$ in the unit square to the *left* of the line $y_{1}=y_{2}$. Hence, in that region, $y_{1}\leq y_{2}$, since "to the left" indicates that the $y_{1}$ values in that region should be *less than* the $y_{1}$ values on the line $y_{1}=y_{2}$.

It follows that, in that region, $0\leq y_{1} \leq y_{2} \leq 1$.

Side note: An equivalent way of looking at it is that the region is all of the points in the unit square *above* the line $y_{1}=y_{2}$, giving $y_{2}\geq y_{1}$, by similar reasoning to the above.

Comment: Thx it helped but I am still confused about the limits of integration

Comment: Fix $y_{2}$ for the moment. We are taking all the points $(y_{1},y_{2})$ to the left of the line $y_{1}=y_{2}$. Noting that $y_{2}$ has been *fixed* for the moment, this tells us exactly what the greatest value of $y_{1}$ will be: it must be $y_{2}$ (any less and we'd still be left of the line, any greater and we'd be on the right of the line and would have "gone too far"). That essentially gives the limits for $y_{1}$. Now we range $y_{2}$ from $0$ to $1$, I think is clear from the diagram: look where the bottom and top of the triangle are; what are their heights?

Answer (score 0):

$0\leq y_1\leq y_2 \leq 1$ means that all three of these are true:

- $y_1\geq 0$
- $y_2 \leq 1$
- $y_2 \geq y_1$

Plotting these on a graph of $y_2$ versus $y_1$, the common area is inside the right triangle formed by the lines $y_1=0, y_2=1, y_2=y_1$.

That is all.

---

PS: As Will R suggests, the picture is just inappropriately labelled.   Substitute $Y_1$ for $X$ and $Y_2$ for $Y$ .